# How to create a native like-button (Not Facebook like button)

Tags: module, magento2.2, social-buttons

I am not sure if I am looking for the wrong term, or we really do not have any extension or tutorial on how to create a native like-button in Magento.

Is there any way to create a like-button that is native, and users can like products simply by clicking on a "heart" icon (for example) in the product's page and be able to see what products they liked in their profiles?

Please note that I am not looking for a Facebook or any other third-party integration, but a "native" like-button.

Thank you in advance.

---

Update:

My intention is to create a like-button that coexists with the "Save for later" button. For the "Save" button, I am using the wishlist feature, but I am not able to transform the wishlist into a like feature since it is already being used as a "save-for-later" feature.

[image: Showing wishlist button next to the like-button]

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a wishlist and it comes [natively](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/wishlist-configuration.html) with Magento 2.

Comment: Not really, I am not talking about the wishlist. I am talking about a simple like button. Wishlist is a "save for later" function, on the other hand, the "like-button" is only a yes/not function. in many online stores, these two functions are separated, and wishlist is simply has a different practical application.

Comment: Practical application means how you use a feature IMO. I can understand why you think this is not a wish list since I've experienced it with many customers, but if you are not planning to use the wishlist as it is, then what you want is just a wishlists with a different style/title (or not, since it comes with a heart as you wanted) and a lot of money saved in development hours.

Comment: We can surely get the feature by modifying the wishlist, and I thank you for commenting on this. Just to be clear about what I need to achieve,  I have added a screenshot to the original question. This screenshot shows how the like-button and "save" are two different functions, and this is basically what I am trying to achieve.